# deploy nuxt3 app on static hosting, error MIME type of ""

Tags: vue.js, nuxtjs3

I am trying to publish a nuxt3 app in a static file hosting, specifically "webempresa", I ran the npm run generate command for the static implementation, when I copy the files in the hosting and try to enter the site I get this error in console. What could be the problem? Thank you

Error:

> Failed to load module script: entry-726afa3a.mjs:1. Expected a
> JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of
> "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML
> spec

Comment: Hi, you should not `copy` the files but probably have a git flow where you push remotely, then `npm run generate` and then `npm run start`. Does it work if you try that locally (build for production)?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your time. I think I found the problem, the hosting doesn't have nodeJs, the files created when I run npm run generate are mjs extensions, so the app can't read the files. So, I added some lines in nuxt.config.ts to export the files with js extension, that works for me

Comment: You don't need a NodeJS server to server a Nuxt static app. Feel free to post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

With these lines in nuxt.config.ts I change the extension of the .mjs files to .js. In this way the application is displayed correctly in the hosting.

```
hooks: {
    'vite:extendConfig'(config, {isClient}) {
      if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development' && isClient) {
        config.build.rollupOptions.output.chunkFileNames = '[name]-[hash].js'
        config.build.rollupOptions.output.entryFileNames = '[name]-[hash].js'
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

updating nuxt to latest worked for us.

```
"nuxt": "^3.0.0-rc.3", -> "nuxt": "^3.0.0-rc.11",
```